# my click's counter program wont work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

After importing the modules and declaring the variables here is how my code starts:

```
while True:

    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dibujarCirculo()
            cont += 1
    contador = texto.render("Clicks: " + str(cont), 1, green)
    ventana.blit(contador, CONT_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

When i run it i get the screen fill with black, and some text "Clicks :0" and when i click the mouse, instead of turning "Clicks: 1" the 1 stacks over the zero and it becomes a mess.
My intention is simply: when you click somewhere in the window it adds 1 to a click's counter. Also it actually draw a circle but that's not important.

i will post the whole code if you want to give it a look.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.constants import *


pygame.init()

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Basics")

red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
darkBlue = (0, 0, 128)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
pink = (255, 200, 200)

cont = 0
CONT_POS = (50, 100)

texto = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

def dibujarCirculo():
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    radius = 10
    pygame.draw.circle(ventana, white, pos, radius)


cont = 0

while True:

    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dibujarCirculo()
            cont += 1
    contador = texto.render("Clicks: " + str(cont), 1, green)
    ventana.blit(contador, CONT_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

note: it is the second time i am posting these because people is voting down for no reason and also tagging the post as off-topic when i try to explain my problem the best way i know...

Comment: People are downvoting because they think that you should debug this yourself before posting the question. Also you should post a minimal example where the problem still occurs.

Comment: What you're seeing is that you're always drawing on top of the canvas (ventana) without clearing it first. I would wager that the circles also stay on the screen despite only being drawn on the mouse click. 
You need to clear the screen before drawing to it (or put a black square over the score) I would imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the screen to avoid drawing on top of the old text

```
while True: 
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dibujarCirculo()
            cont += 1
    ventana.fill((0,0,0)) # clear the screen
    contador = texto.render("Clicks: " + str(cont), 0, green)
    ventana.blit(contador, CONT_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

You can add  the blit using black in your first function to just overwrite the blit each time.

```
def dibujarCirculo():
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    radius = 10
    pygame.draw.circle(ventana, white, pos, radius)
    contador = texto.render("Clicks: " + str(cont), 0, black) # set background to black
    ventana.blit(contador, CONT_POS)


while True:
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dibujarCirculo()
            cont += 1
    contador = texto.render("Clicks: " + str(cont), 1, green)
    ventana.blit(contador, CONT_POS)
    pygame.display.update()
```